# create single bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, stack, bar-chart

```r
g5 <- ggplot(data = D1, aes(x = Rating , fill=Rating)) + 
  geom_bar(col = "black", position = "stack") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 360, hjust = 1)) + 
  scale_x_discrete("Rating Grade")
```

I create a bar chart using code, Now I want to plot bar chart with one single bar.

I want to draw one single stacked bar chart

Comment: Remove rating from x aesthetic